# MutationObserver for new created element?

Tags: javascript, dom, styles, mutation-observers

How to MutationObserver for new created element? When I create a new element, mutatonObserver does not work. I need to register if the giant box has changed style ...

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Create</button>
<button onclick="myFunctionStyle()">Change style</button>
```

```
var observerm = new MutationObserver(function(mutationsm) {
    mutationsm.forEach(function(mutationRecord) {
        alert('style changed!');
    });    
});

var targetm = document.getElementById("Box");
observerm.observe(targetm, { attributes : true, attributeFilter : ['style'] });


function myFunction() {
  var newdiv = document.createElement("DIV");
  newdiv.innerHTML = "Box";
  newdiv.id = "Box";
  newdiv.style.width = "100px";
  newdiv.style.height = "50px";
  newdiv.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  
  document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
}

function myFunctionStyle() {
  document.getElementById("Box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the newly added elements are appended to the `document.body`, that's the element you need to attach another MutationObserver to.

```
new MutationObserver(() => {
  console.log('mutation on document body');
  // rest of the code you need when an element is appended
})
  .observe(document.body, { childList: true })
```

Comment: everything works normally but if a new element is created, simply mutationObserver does not register it

Comment: If the element is never appended, the only way to detect it would be to overwrite and patch the `createElement` method on `document`. If you don't know *where* it'll be appended, but it will be appended somewhere, you could either do that, or attach a recursive observer with `subtree: true` in addition to the childList prop.

Comment: In this example, I specified the create element in the document.body, but I need it within other created elements. Div inside div ..., inside div ..., I'm trying with your explanation but it doesn't work again

Comment: Best solution would be to identify each container you're interested in and attach an observer to each, with `childList: true`.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but every parent is also created ..., so ... hm

Comment: Add an observer to *their* parents then - perhaps with `subtree: true` so you can identify not only added children, but grandchildren as well.